# Show files uploaded of a particular format on ftp server using python

Tags: python, flask, ftp

I am working on a ftp webapp. I have created everything till uploading part, i.e, File is successfully uploaded into ftpuser's directory. Now I am providing users option to see files they uploaded by format. Example: if users clicks on icon of browse images then they should be shown all the images they have uploaded.

Commands like "Retr" starts downloading files other than texts and pdf but I want to enlist all the files and not download. I have no idea about how to do this.

I am using Flask for webapp and ftplib for uploading.

Comment: `help(ftplib)` shows you how: `ftp.retrlines('LIST')` lists the directory content and `ftp.cwd` lets you change directories.

Comment: ftp.retrlines('LIST') & ftp.nlst() works. This displays name of files uploaded. Thanks

Comment: Is there any method that I can show files with the names. Like previewing the file?

Comment: Do you mean "show **contents of the** files with the names"?

Comment: Not the content exactly but their icons along with their names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By suggestions made by @tdelaney. I formed the solution by uploading different file formats to a different directory in ftp user's directory. So when the user clicks on display images he is displayed names of files in the images folder. Code for the following is given below:

```
if c=='images':
            ftp=FTP('127.0.0.1',userid,passwd)
            if not 'images' in ftp.nlst():
                ftp.mkd('images')
            ftp.cwd('images')

elif c=='documents':
            ftp=FTP('127.0.0.1',userid,passwd)
            if not 'documents' in ftp.nlst():
                ftp.mkd('documents')
            ftp.cwd('documents')

elif c=='audios':
            ftp=FTP('127.0.0.1',userid,passwd)
            if not 'audios' in ftp.nlst():
                ftp.mkd('audios')
            ftp.cwd('audios')

elif c=='videos':
           ftp=FTP('127.0.0.1',userid,passwd)
           if not 'videos' in ftp.nlst():
            ftp.mkd('videos')
           ftp.cwd('videos')
else:
            ftp=FTP('127.0.0.1',userid,passwd)
            if not 'others' in ftp.nlst():
                ftp.mkd('others')
            ftp.cwd('others')
files=ftp.nlst()
```

and further ftp.nlst() is used to get the list of files in that directory which is then passed to template and printed by following code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for file in files %}
            <td>{{file}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```